# Setting up a grid of of dynamic divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently trying to set up a grid with my html. My content is settled in a bootstrap `.container`. This content is a collection of divs. The number of divs varies based on an external process. If there is an even number of divs then I want a 2xn grid. If there is an odd number of divs I want a grid as well but I want the last div to be centered in its own block. I have been able to achieve this with the following code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="targetcontainer">
    <div class="target">
        <p>content goes here man</p>
    </div>
    <div class="target">
        <p>content goes here man</p>
    </div>
    <div class="target">
        <p>content goes here man</p>
    </div>
    <div class="target">
        <p>content goes here man</p>
    </div>
    <div class="target">
        <p>content goes here man</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.target {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47%;
  min-width: 400px;
  height: 265px;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  padding: 2%;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
function addClassToLastElement() {
  $('.target').each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(this).is(":last-child") && index % 2 == 0) {
      $(this).css('display', 'block')
      $(this).css('margin', '0 auto')
    }
  })
}

addClassToLastElement()
```

My jQuery code determines whether there is an odd number of elements. If there is then it adds the appropriate properties and centers the last div. You can see this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/12wsn4pb/1/)(make sure the result screen is relatively large).

The issue arises when you shrink the screen. When there is a window shrink the divs stack on top of each other, which is what I want. The thing is that they don't center in the middle of the screen except for the last one. If you examine the last div thats what I want all the divs to be represented when the screen shrinks down to the point that the divs become stack onto each other. Anyone know how to accomplish this without bootstrap and without using jQuery's `.resize()`? I only want to use one bootstrap element and that's the `.container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `text-align: center` to the parent container, all `.target` divs should be centered now

EDIT:

```
/* The container itself */
.container{
    text-align: center;
}

/* every element, that is inside */
.container *{
    text-align: left;
}
```

EDIT 2: (with second container)

https://jsfiddle.net/12wsn4pb/6/

Comment: This centers my content in my `p` element. I don't want this.

Comment: This is the way I want my divs to behave though!

Comment: try this: 
 `.container{
    text-align: center;
}

.container *{
    text-align: left;
} `

Comment: Close, but didn't work. Note that there are two containers. Tried it on jsFiddle.

Comment: You left out the `targetcontainer` div on jsFiddle. So just apply the rules to the parent element of your targets. That should work. Or do I miss something here?

Comment: btw: jsFiddle changes the url of your code with every update. In your question there is `/1/` for your initial code

Answer (score 0):

Another option- if you're making this responsive- would be to use media queries. If the width of the window is less than 820px then apply the margin to your targets.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
    .target {
        display: block;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
}
```